# How to open MDI files?

Tags: files

Does anybody know what package shall I download or what to do to open `.MDI` files on Ubuntu 13.10?

MDI: *Microsoft Document Imaging Format*

Answer (score 0):

You need to register/sign up to use the service but http://www.freepdfconvert.com/  can convert MDI to PDF, PNG or JPG. (See the [supported formats](http://www.freepdfconvert.com/conversion-types))

I don't think there's a package able to open that kind of file.